# Problem solving equation of type x=a*b^x

Tags: problem-solving

I have the equation x = a*b^x and want to solve it for x. But every online solver I tried says that it is not possible.

But when I choose a==8 and b==0.5 there is a solution for x==2

Is it not possible to solve the equation formally?

Comment: The eager closers have done their (dirty) work here.  If you want more information about this use of the Lambert W function, try asking at one of the other locations found in the FAQ.  For example http://math.stackexchange.com/ 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no elementary formulas for such equations. Using the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), the solution is $$x = -\frac{W(-a \log b)}{\log b}$$